# Android 2.2 Implements Runnable Public void run() not being called

Tags: android, runnable

I have the following:-

```
public class resApp extends MapActivity implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        searchImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

I also have a background thread that runs before this but that seems to run ok.

When i run the app the run() never gets called.

Can you help?
This code did work about 6 months ago but the device was 2.1.

Thanks

Chris

---

edit

I had already implemented

```
 private Handler handler;

 handler = new Handler() {
 @Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    if (msg.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
    ad.dismiss();
    } else {
    pd.dismiss();
    }
}
 };
```

as an example and I already have an asynchronous task that runs in the back ground and in 2.1 I could have getters and setters in there. I have now had to pull these out and put them into the run() method as 2.2 doesn't like setting onclicklistener in an async task.
All I need to do is call the run() method on post execute but have tried everything:-

```
protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
// Pass the result data back to the main activity
if (dialog != null) {
    resApp.this.dialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

Could I just do:-

```
 handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    this.resApp.run();
}
 };
```

Comment: Your code is very incomplete. Runnable.run isn't called on its own, it may be called from Handler.

Comment: Hi mice, take a look at my edit above, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the run() method by using Handler.

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler();
resApp myObj;
```

And call it by using `myHandler.post(myObj);`

Comment: thanks but this doesn't work, do you have other ideas as to what could call the run method. Like I say the same code was working on a different device.

Comment: You want to continue running thread or execute it only once..?

Comment: what do you mean by this.."2.2 doesn't like setting onclicklistener in an async task"?

Comment: If I put a setOnclickListener into the doInbackground method of an asynchronous task I get an error. Worked previously for different target but now my target is 2.2 and no longer woks.

Comment: What error do you get while setting OnClickListener in AsyncTask?

Comment: 09-20 11:05:20.325: ERROR/dalvikvm(24354): could not disable core file generation for pid 24354, errno=1

Comment: 09-20 11:05:20.981: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24354): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Comment: I read on a forum recently that you can no longer put setOnclicklistener and such like into an asynch thread

Comment: like this:-  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() { MyDialog.Prompt(NameOfYourActivity.this); }
    });
if so when I try to wrap my run method in this it just gives me also sorts of compilation errors.

Comment: do i put this inside my asynchronous task method?

Comment: Yes, you can put it inside your AsyncTask and it will work fine, if you have anymore problem come to casual chat room.